# Doing conditional count with ActiveRecord objects

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, rails-activerecord, enumerable

```
Food.where(meat: true).count do |food|
  food.chunky?
end
```

just does the same thing as `Food.where(meat: true).count`, as an SQL-style count is being done, rather than an `Enumerable#count` type of count.

Is there any way of doing an `Enumerable#count` type of count other than tacking on an `each`, like the following?

```
Food.where(meat: true).each.count do |food|
  food.chunky?
end
```

(Yes, I realise doing `food.chunky?` involves creating `food` objects and calling a method on them, rather than doing everything at the database level - sometimes it can't be avoided)

Answer (score 1):

This might work (note: not tested).

```
Food.where(meat: true).select{|f| f.chunky? }.count
```